# How to merge node_modules from local required modules

Tags: node.js, npm, package, local

I'm building a modular nodejs app, I have the following folder structure:

```
- main_app
 - index.js
 - package.json 
- plugin_1
 - index.js
 - package.json
 - package-lock.json
- plugin_2
 - index.js
 - package.json
 - package-lock.json
```

And I have required locally from `main_app`, `plugin_1` and `plugin_2`. Like:

```
{
  "name": "main_app",
  "dependencies": {
    "plugin_1": "file:../plugin_1",
    "plugin_2": "file:../plugin_2"
  }
}
```

Without running `npm install` on the `plugin_1` and `plugin_2`, but on `main_app`. NPM succesfully install the dependencies on `plugin_1` and `plugin_2`, and the main application runs fine. I'm left with the following folder structure:

```
- main_app
 - index.js
 - package.json 
 - package-lock.json
 - node_modules/
- plugin_1
 - index.js
 - package.json
 - package-lock.json
 - node_modules/
- plugin_2
 - index.js
 - package.json
 - package-lock.json
 - node_modules/
```

However if I have the same dependency for any of `plugin_1`, `plugin_2`, or `main_app`, it'll install it every time on each folder. With big dependencies this is a problem on resource limited systems.

Ideally I'd like it to install the dependencies on `main_app/node_modules` just once, like the following:

```
- main_app
 - index.js
 - package.json 
 - package-lock.json
 - node_modules/
- plugin_1
 - index.js
 - package.json
 - package-lock.json
- plugin_2
 - index.js
 - package.json
 - package-lock.json
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it necessary for you to have a separate package.json in plugin_1 and plugin_2 folders?

Comment: yes, they are different projects with different dependencies, or what do you mean?

Comment: If you want a "global" node_modules, there's no need for separate configuration files. Just put all of the dependencies in the "global" configuration files (main_app folder), and this will create a single node_modules folder.

Comment: Ok, I understand. What I don't want is to put the dependencies of the plugins on the main_app's package.json. I want plugin_1 to be self contained the same way you don't specify dependencies of the packages you install from npm's registry.

Comment: I guess if there's no NPM way of doing it I can write a script to parse and merge package.json's into the main_app's and use your solution.